# How am I fix text Alignment and language support for text which parsed from json

Tags: android, json, android-activity, textview

I am developing an android app, which show **title** (text) from json in ListView Activity. After click ListItem Users will go another activity. Where  i parse **Poem** from json. This is the screenshot. [http://imgur.com/a/sBfx9Cy](https://imgur.com/a/sBfx9Cy)
My problem is -

(1) Text Alignment, I want show that parsed poem in a centre Alignment...

(2) My poem is also in another language but after it show this - [http://imgur.com/a/Hp9XejV](https://imgur.com/a/Hp9XejV)

Also in english language, its not parse exact, which i have written in json..

Please help me to solve it....

Thanks

Comment: you need to add custom font for the language you want to support if its not installed on the phone. also for english it looks like encoding issue. make sure you are using correct format.

Comment: How can I add,  this is my json favourite -  http://movies-guy.000webhostapp.com/value.json